# How can I make my array columns uniform on numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a 10x10 Matrix but the second one looks disordered, any suggestion?

Here is the code:

```
m=10
t = 25
M = np.random.randint(-t,+t,(m,m))
print(M)
P=(M-M.min())/(M.max()-M.min())
print("Matriu normalitzada\n:",P,sep="")
```

Comment: `M = np.random.rand(m,m)`?

Comment: Maybe use this formatting before printing `np.set_printoptions(floatmode='fixed',linewidth=200)`